# Swift How to access parameter in function

Tags: swift

I have something like this:

```
enum Op {
    case Operation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
}
```

Now I want to do this:

```
var description: String {
    get {
        switch Op {
            case .Operation(let symbol, /* how can I access the two (Double, Double) from (Double, Double) -> Double? */ ):
                return Double1 + symbol + Double2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question:

> how can I access the two `(Double, Double)`

...makes no sense. There are no Doubles to access. The second value is a `(Double, Double) -> Double`. That's a *function*. Not a *called* function; just a function. The terms Double denote *types*, not *values*.

You could *capture* this function. You could *call* this function, *yourself*. But there are no Doubles there. Do you see?

Here's an example of actual working code; try it in a playground:

```
enum Op {
    case Operation(String, (Double, Double) -> Double)
}

func f (x:Double, y:Double) -> Double { return x + y }

let op = Op.Operation("howdy", f)

switch op {
case .Operation(let symbol, let function) :
    print(symbol) // Howdy
    print(function(1,2)) // 3
}
```

Do you see? I didn't *fetch* the two Doubles; I *supplied* them.

Comment: Is there no way to give that function values with the Double as type? Like I did with the String and ´let symbol´?

Comment: Look at the code I've given you. I've shown you what you can do. — If you don't understand what `(Double, Double) -> Double` _is_, why are you even _using_ it in this way? Is this code you copied without knowing what you were copying?